# Make drawimage in Javascript to fade out

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, javascript-objects, game-engine, dom-events

I have asked a similar question previously however I did not receive a solution.

I currently have 7 bugs dropping from the top to the bottom. I want the user to be able to click on a single bug which will cause it to fade out / disappear. I would need some sort of detection if the mouse is within the image, on click will allow it to fade out or else no effect.

This is crucial as I will include a scoring system whereby for every hit 1 points will be gained and for every miss 1 point will be lost.

```
var noOfBugs = 7;
var bug = [];
for(var i =0; i < noOfBugs; i++){
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

bug[i] = new Bug(x,y);
}

imageBug = new Image();
imageBug.src = "imgs/redbug.png";

 function Bug (x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y =y;

    this.drop = function(){
    var dir = Math.floor(Math.random())*3;
    if(dir == 0){
        this.x = this.x;
    }



    this.y = this.y+1;
    if(this.y > canvas.height){
        this.y=0;
    }
 }

this.show = function (){
context.drawImage(imageBug, this.x, this.y)

}
}


function draw (){
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
for(var i=0; i<noOfBugs; i++){
    bug[i].show();
    bug[i].drop();
}
}
// Mouse click on bug 
canvas.onclick = function (event){
  var mouseX = event.clientX;
  var mouseY = event.clientY;

if (mouseX === x && mouseY === y){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  context.globalAlpha = 0.1;
  context.drawImage(imageBug, this.x, this.y, imageX, imageY);

  alert("its a hit");
}

else {
  alert("You missed");

  score -= 0;
}

}

 function reload (){
    draw ();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(reload);
 }

 reload();
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the mouse:

```
mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    down: false
};

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event => {

    var bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Get mouse position INSIDE canvas.
    mouse.x = ((event.clientX - bounds.left) / (bounds.right - bounds.left)) * canvas.width;
    mouse.y = ((event.clientY - bounds.top) / (bounds.bottom - bounds.top)) * canvas.height;

    if(event.which == 1) { // If mouse was left clicked.
        mouse.down = true;
    } else {
        mouse.down = false;
    }

}));

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (event => {

    if(event.which == 1) { // If mouse was left clicked.
        mouse.down = true;
    } else {
        mouse.down = false;
    }

}));

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (event => {
    mouse.down = false; // If mouse click was released.
}));
```

Since the mouse is a 2d point and a bug is a 2d rectangle, you could use this dot-in-box function:

```
function dotInBox(point, rect) {
    return (
        point.x > rect.x &&
        point.x < rect.x + rect.width &&
        point.y > rect.y &&
        point.y < rect.y + rect.height
    );
}
```

`point` would be `mouse` and `rect` would be an object representing the bug’s bounding box.

To fade the bug out, I recommend you use `context.globalAlpha`. You can find it’s documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha.

Just use this psuedocode along with the other snippets and you’re done!

```
if mouse is down:
  for var i = 0. i < length of bugs. increment i:
    if mouse touching current bug:
      make current bug fade.

in update loop:
  for var i = 0. i < length of bugs. increment i:
    if bug is fading:
      lower current bug’s opacity.
    if bug is completely faded:
      delete current bug.
      decrement i. (since the bug was removed, you would accidentally skip a bug)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code - How would i apply this to my code provided bearing in mind a sprite will be used to remove the bug

Comment: @CodingJunkie What do you mean ‘a sprite will be used to cover the bug’? You mean to cover it?

Comment: With reference to your code, if the position of the mouse is inside the bug image when being clicked the bug must fade out (I have created a fade out effect within the sprite image) - Hope this makes sense

Comment: For transparent images, I think you should use context.globalAlpha. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha

Comment: If you can kindly view the code i have posted below, at my attempt to adapt your code to mine - Thanks !

Comment: You’re welcome! The code seems fine. Could you comment your edited code or post a link to a JsFliddle (or similar) next time?

Comment: Yes no worries - apologies ! I am new on here so still learning the ropes

Comment: I have removed my answer due to the mistake of posting, i have included the edit of the same code within your answer. If you could ammend the psuedo - much appreciated !

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Just wondering, could you make the indentation in the code of your question a little more conventional? (It’s a bit hard to read as it is.)

Comment: I have managed to put together the mouse click function which i was looking for. When i set my score using alerts it was calcuating it correctly, however using .innerHTML the score does not seem to change and stays at 0 ? - https://jsfiddle.net/nk001/0eu6h510/14

Comment: You don’t seem to have an element with ID 'Score'. Btw, why do you have css style for `#cat` if it’s not an element?

Comment: I have declared score = 0 at the top, how would I setup the scoring system ? Is my code structured correctly ? also regarding the css that should have been removed as it was used for something previously

Comment: You score is not displaying because `document.getElementById('Score')` needs to find an HTML element with an id of 'Score' (kinda like `<p id="Score"></p>`). Your HTML doesn’t have one and your JavaScript is not putting one there.

Comment: Here is my updated code, i have finally managed to run the score system on click of the image - However how would i add 0 to the score whilst globalAlpha is = 0.1 ? To prevent users gaining points whilst it is restoring- https://jsfiddle.net/nk001/2sj6v73p/

Comment: I have added my own 'Mouse click on bug' code, however the mouseX and Y cannot recognise the position of the bug - What can i change within the IF statement ?

Comment: Use a variable for if the picture was just clicked (I’ll call it `just_clicked`). In the canvas onclick, add a `just_clicked = true; setTimeout(redraw, 3000);` and remove `setInterval(redraw, 3000);`. Wrap the whole code inside the canvas onclick in an if statement that only activates if `!just_clicked`. In redraw, add `just_clicked = false;`. That’ll do that after you click the picture, you cant click again (from `just_clicked` being `true`) and redraw will be called in 3 seconds, which will set `just_clicked` back to `false`, so you can click it again!

Comment: **Side note:** your code considers clicking to the top left space over the cat *still* clicking the cat.

Comment: The issue I am facing is my code above (not the cat) is not recognising my cursor when it is on the bug image, which variables would I use within the if statement. I initially used imageX and imageY for the cat which worked however when using the same method in my own bug code it didn’t work ?

Comment: Your code would be easier to debug you used the mouse object and gave the bug class a width and height *(to use `dotInBox`)*. Could you please do that?